# Script allowing the Toggle between two scripts by one key?

Tags: maya, hotkeys

I use the hot keys for two scripts in maya, A key for A script and B key for B script 
Instead of this, is it possible to toggle between two scripts,by just using one key. 
For example,  when I push the A key first, it runs the A script, then I push the A button again, it runs the second script, and loop.

Is it possible in ?

then, what I have to add in two scripts ?

Thank you guys, I will really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a hotkey, you just create a [`runTimeCommand` object](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-2B2BE446-D622-4274-80FC-2A5EF7D87C5C-htm.html) using the Maya UI or with [`cmds.runtTimeCommand`](http://eeltechart.com/maya/sharing-maya-runtimecommands/) in Python.  The script will handle the toggling and then call the other scripts.

If you just want the toggle behavior in a single session, you'd do something like this:

```
global script_state
try:
    script_state = not script_state
except NameError:
    script_state = True

if script_state:
    print "on"
else:
    print "off"


script_state = not script_state
```

If you run that several times in the listener you'll see it toggling after each run.  You'd just replace the prints with your actual functions.